# Is there a framework to study quantitative model robustness/uncertainty?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, models

Can you point me to any resources about a possible framework to analyse and possibly quantify model uncertainty and -robustness associated with quantitative investment models?

As an example, there might be an obscure trading strategy, which, every 5 years chooses one new stock to invest into. Now, if this inherently random strategy would happen to once invest into a stock that increases 100-fold over the five year period, it is quite likely, that the strategy's return/risk and t-stat would look great. Now, compare this to some established strategy, such as cross-sectional momentum: while the former might have a clearly higher t-stat, it is clear, that it is a much less robust model, and there is much more uncertainty about the true alpha achievable by investing according to the model. While it might be easy to come up with a working robustness test for this dummy example, can any of you point me to any general frameworks for approaching the issue?

Off the top of my head, I could see, for example the following questions used to assess model robustness:

-How robust are the results to a change in the sample (investment universe, time period, etc.)?

-How robust are the results to a slight change in model specification?

-What are the model's static exposures to (non-rewarded) risk factors (if a model has made only one active decision to be long in the Information Technology sector and short the Energy sector during the 2010s, the results are likely to be much less robust than for another model that chooses a varying set of new stocks every day)?

-If applicable, how many, and how prestigious papers have been written about the subject?

-Is there an underlying economic rationale to the model?

Comment: This is related: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2249314.

Comment: Thanks! That paper was actually the only one I was aware of. However, that framework is quite simplistic and doesn't really address model robustness. It, for example, couldn't make a distinction between the strategies in the dummy example in the question.